# CodeIgniter URL & Nested Controller architecture

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, url

THe project i am working on is multilanguage, and i wish to have a url that would look like that :

```
/en/articles/category/article_id
```

I was hoping to have EN be the main controller so that i can extend it to produce over languages (CN)

Is there a clean way to achieve that using CI.

Thanks a lots

Answer (score 0):

You should in fact adjust your routing to omit the language identifier in the url and load the regular controllers.
The language identifier will just help in loading the right language file.

http://sumonbd.wordpress.com/2009/09/16/develop-multilingual-site-using-codeigniter-i18n-library/ this might help you out.